# Laravel 5.4 - 'updateOrCreate' method. Check If record was 'updated' or 'created'

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Using the method `updateOrCreate`, is there a way to know which if a record was updated or created?

**UPDATE:**
I need to use this feature to return `201`, for created record, or `204` for updated record.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `updateOrCreate` returns the model instance.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L374

You can check that a record was recently created using:
`$instance->wasRecentlyCreated`
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1593

Comment: What if the record exists, but actually wasn't updated?

Comment: Check if the instance of the model is dirty using `$instance->isDirty()`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, if calling `isDirty` after the `updateOrCreate` or `firstOrCreate` on the returned Model, it is my understanding that the Model being checked will always return `false` as the operations will have already been performed to update or create the model. I think another property needs to be added, `wasRecentlyUpdated`. This property could be updated at least once, within the `performUpdate` function. There may be other functions, like the `save` function, where updating the property may make sense.